# SQL query assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a table in my database that looks like this:

```
ID | Delaytype     | Delaysubtype      | Delay Hours | Delay Date
1    Engineering     machine breakdown        4         2015-01-28
2    Human Error     Forgot to check          4         2015-02-27

3    Engineering     Machine                  2         2015-03-23
4    Engineering     Machine                  3         2015-04-10
5    Human Error     Forgot something         1         2015-05-10
```

Now based on this data I am already outputting graphs but I need to create a more detailed view.

Basically someone from a dropdown selects the delaytype.

and from this I am trying to show a breakdown of the delaysubtype associated with the delaytype in the form of hours between specified dates.

Currently the user selects a :from date , to date and a Delaytype.

From this using the engineering example above I want

```
machine breakdown 4
machine 5
```

I have produced this query but it does not work and is really starting to push my basic knowledge of SQL commands:

```
 "SELECT delaysubtype FROM delays WHERE delaytype = .userinputdelaytype. WHERE Delaydate BETWEEN .userInputFromDate. AND .userInputToDate.,sum(Delayhours) as cnt"
```

Any help is much appreciated. Also any good resource or tutorials on building more complex queries i.e structure of statements would help.

Comment: What means "this query but it does not work "?

Comment: I am getting an error indicating that the SQL is not correct. The PHP is correct in my script as I have used the same script to output less detailed results with the same php posts I am literally just changing the query within the PHP script

Comment: Add the relevant php code too please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
$qry = "
    SELECT 
        delaysubtype,
        sum(Delayhours) as cnt
    FROM 
        delays 
    WHERE 
        delaytype = ".$userinputdelaytype."
        AND Delaydate BETWEEN ".$userInputFromDate." AND ".$userInputToDate."
    GROUP BY
        delaysubtype"
```

Your example looked like a PHP code so I tried to give answer in PHP.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this it helped greatly and worked. I did it slightly differently and will add but this was massively helpful getting the order of commands in the right order

Comment: Hi. That's good that you've manage to go further with your work :) Thx also and regards.